# Suggestion to make tag "p" a synonym of tag "p-value"

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Currently the tag [p-value](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/p-value) has 218 threads under it.

The tag [p](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/p) has only 3 posts subordinated to it.
All the three `p` questions refer to "p-value" concept.

Is it possible to make them synonyms with [p-value](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/p-value) as the master?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good catch! I've merged the two, and the master tag is now [p-value](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/p-value).

Comment: Thank's a lot.!